# Which is the density function for Y? Which is the distribution function for Y?

Tags: probability, random-variables

Let $X$ a random variable with $Binomial(4,\frac{1}{2})$. Let $Y = (2*X-4)^2$. Which is the density function for Y? Which is the distribution function for Y?

My try:

Well we know that $f_X(x) = \binom{4}{x}(0.5)^{x}(0.5)^{4-x}$

so then by the change of variable preposition $f_Y(y) = \binom{4}{\frac{\sqrt{y}+4}{2}}(0.5)^{\frac{\sqrt{y}+4}{2}}(0.5)^{4-\frac{\sqrt{y}+4}{2}}(\frac{1}{4\sqrt{y}})$

My problem is that the calculation of $\binom{4}{\frac{\sqrt{y}+4}{2}}$ is not defined. Any suggestions?

Comment: Observe that $Y$ is a discrete variable, which can take only a finite number of values, each of them with some probability. Your distribution function will be piecewise constant and the density (in the sense of measures) is a sum of delta-functions at the possible values. You cannot use the change of variable formula in this discrete case.

Answer (score 1):

The first thing to do is figure out the support of $Y$.  Let $g(x) = (2x-4)^2 = 4(x-2)^2$.  Then for $x \in \{0, 1, 2, 3, 4\}$, we find $$\begin{align*} g(0) = g(4) &= 16, \\ g(1) = g(3) &= 4, \\ g(2) &= 0. \end{align*}$$  So $$Y \in \{0, 4, 16\}.$$  Then 
$$\begin{align*}
\Pr[Y = 0] &= \Pr[X = 2], \\ \Pr[Y = 4] &= \Pr[X = 1] + \Pr[X = 3], \\ \Pr[Y = 16] &= \Pr[X = 0] + \Pr[X = 4]. 
\end{align*}$$  The rest is straightforward.